# javascript with table bold

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a javascript code which he gave me in bold but he weiterhelft bold only the time-not the text next to it and I will both have bold it is also possible to bold multiple tables

```js
var hour = new Date().getHours() + 1;

$('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, td) {
    if ($(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 0) {
        $(td).addClass('highlight-time');
    } else {
        $(td).removeClass('highlight-time');
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight-time {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class to the `tr` as follow:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours() + 1;

$('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, td) {
    if ($(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 0) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('highlight-time');
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('highlight-time');
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/4myr3wqp/1/

**EDIT**

Using `toggleClass`:

```
$('table td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, td) {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('highlight-time', ($(td).text().indexOf(hour) == 0));
});
```

Comment: even in `else` you might want to remove from `tr`.. :)

Comment: you could use toggleClass also so you dont repeat yourself

Comment: but nothing is bold, I do not know way hir is a link of the codes I pretext and I want that too the text is automatically bold. not only the time-

http://jsfiddle.net/sah27uo6/3/

Comment: @TonTonii do you have the JS code down at the closing </body> tag or in a DOM-ready `$(function(){})` wrapper? (but your jsfiddle display a bold text on my machine)

Comment: @TonTonii Did You wrap Your code in `ready` as voigtan said above

Comment: I clicked on the web that you posted above in comments but I seer no bold option :( :(

Comment: ok now works .I thank you .and I apologize for my bad english